# stringify'ing generic c# object in html, parsing in JS

Tags: javascript, json, razor

In razor, this is what I have:

```
<span data="@(new { prop1 = "prop1val", prop2 = 5 })" id="span1"></span>
```

And, in JS, I want to parse that data attr val into a JSON object.

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse($("#span1").attr("data"));
alert(dataObj.prop1); // should alert "prop1val"
```

The way the razor is rendering is like this:

```
<span data="{ prop1 = prop1val, prop2 = 5 }" id="span1"></span>
```

Do I need to do something like @(new {...}).toJsonString() ? Is there something within razor I can just use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize the string to JSON format.

You can write `@(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { ... }))`

If you want to, you can create an extension method to do that as an HTML helper:

```
public static string ToJson(this HtmlHelper html, object obj) {
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
}
```